# Getting first day of the week in MySql using Week No

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the first day of a given week whose week number is available?

For example as I write this post we are at **WEEK 29**.I would like to write a MySQL query that will return **Sunday 18 July** using this **WEEKNO 29** as the only available parameter.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201003 Monday', '%X%V %W');
```

This would give you the Monday date of week 3 of 2010, which would be 2010-01-18.

Another example:

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201052 Sunday', '%X%V %W');
```

Would give you the Sunday date of week 52 of 2010, which would be 2010-12-26.

And finally, using your original example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201029 Sunday', '%X%V %W');
```

This gives 2010-07-18.

Comment: When using week mode 3 (ISO standard, qv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788885/), then SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201003 Monday', '%X%V %W') will give Monday of the following week!

Comment: I think it is not correct. Try to run SELECT STR_TO_DATE(  '201402 Sunday',  '%X%V %W' ) , STR_TO_DATE(  '201402 Monday',  '%X%V %W' ) - you'll see that it is not sunday of 2nd week and monday of 2nd week - it is second sunday and 2nd monday of YEAR

Comment: @ChrisV: My solution for that is to substract 1 week after conversion:
```DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK('201402 Sunday', 3), ' Monday'), '%X%V %W'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)```

Comment: @chrpes: I think that STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), WEEK(CURDATE()) + 1, ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') week_end is a little bit readeable

Comment: @chrpes You may need to use, %x%v instead of %X%V to get your desired result. Because `%X%V` use Sunday as the start day of the month, `%x%v` use Monday as start day of the month..

Answer (score 49):

This is an accurate way of getting the first day of the week and the last day of the week based on the current date:

```
adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY) WeekStart,
adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY) WeekEnd
```

Comment: I think this solution might be affected by the system locale, I use this instead `adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(curdate()) DAY) WeekStart`

Comment: @SnowBlind, thank you for your comment. 
...and if someone is looking for Friday as last day of week (i.e. last Workday), then try this:
     <code>
     adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL 4-WEEKDAY(curdate()) DAY) SHOULD_BE_Friday 
     </code>

Comment: This answer is all good, but didn't this question request for a solution when what you were given is: WEEK NUMBER/ YEARWEEK? This answer really only applies to a case where you have a `date`, or are working with `current_date`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer most liked up to now on this board looks like this in its basic form:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201003 Monday', '%X%V %W');
```

This is a good answer to start with, but it breaks down on some days when you start to put it to use in conjuction with the week() function unless you add some additional logic.

Here is a long, messy version of the same thing, but which seems to work on all days (BTW the current date is built into this asnwer):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
(IF( CAST(WEEK(NOW(),0) AS UNSIGNED) = 0,
(CONCAT(
CAST((CAST(YEAR(NOW()) AS UNSIGNED) - 1) AS CHAR),
'52 Sunday')),
(CONCAT(
CAST(YEAR(NOW()) AS CHAR), 
IF( CAST(WEEK(NOW(),0) AS UNSIGNED) < 10,'0','' ),
CAST(WEEK(NOW(),0) AS CHAR),
' Sunday')))),
'%X%V %W');
```

This mess handles the problems that arise when the year rolls over on certain days of the week.  For instance 2011 started on a Saturday, so the Sunday that started the week was in the prior year.  Here's the select with hard coded examples:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
(IF( CAST(WEEK('2011-01-01',0) AS UNSIGNED) = 0,
(CONCAT(
CAST((CAST(YEAR('2011-01-01') AS UNSIGNED) - 1) AS CHAR),
'52 Sunday')),
(CONCAT(
CAST(YEAR('2011-01-01') AS CHAR), 
IF( CAST(WEEK('2011-01-01',0) AS UNSIGNED) < 10,'0','' ),
CAST(WEEK('2011-01-01',0) AS CHAR),
' Sunday')))),
'%X%V %W');
```

YEILDS >> '2010-12-26'

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
(IF( CAST(WEEK('2011-01-02',0) AS UNSIGNED) = 0,
(CONCAT(
CAST((CAST(YEAR('2011-01-02') AS UNSIGNED) - 1) AS CHAR),
'52 Sunday')),
(CONCAT(
CAST(YEAR('2011-01-02') AS CHAR), 
IF( CAST(WEEK('2011-01-02',0) AS UNSIGNED) < 10,'0','' ),
CAST(WEEK('2011-01-02',0) AS CHAR),
' Sunday')))),
'%X%V %W');
```

YEILDS >> '2011-01-02'

All that said, I like the other asnwer posted that looks like this

```
SELECT
adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY) WeekStart, 
adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY) WeekEnd;
```

This method seems to work just as well on all dates without the mess!

Comment: Couldn't you make this much simpler by using a mode of 2? YEARWEEK('2011-01-01', 2) reports the 52nd week of 2010, as opposed to mode 0, which returns the 0th week of 2011.

Answer (score 4):

This can be the simplest and dynamic way for it. Use the following code.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( concat( concat( date_format( CURDATE( ) , '%Y' ) , WEEKOFYEAR( CURDATE( ) ) ) , ' Monday' ) , '%X%V %W' );
```

Answer (score 2):

If your week-start is Sunday and week-end is Saturday, use this one:

```
SELECT
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (MOD(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1, 7)*-1) DAY) AS week_start,
  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ((MOD(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1, 7)*-1)+6) DAY) AS week_end
```

Tested on MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to dcp's answer:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201553 Monday', '%x%v %W')
```

Will give you the monday when your start of the week is monday. The format specifiers just have to be written small. No math needed.

Answer (score 0):

Untested (I don't have MySQL at hand):

```
date_add(
   date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day),
   interval ((NUM-weekofyear(curdate()))*7) day)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),'Monday'), '%X%V %W'),2),'-', 
        MID(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),'Monday'), '%X%V %W'),6,2),'-',
        LEFT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),'Monday'), '%X%V %W'),4)) AS 'Lundi',

   CONCAT(RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), week(now(),3),'Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),2),'-', 
        MID(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), week(now(),3),'Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),6,2),'-',
        LEFT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), week(now(),3),'Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),4)) AS 'Dimanche';
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with above solution. I ended up to used this:

```
STR_TO_DATE( concat( YEARWEEK("2012-12-31", 3) , ' Monday' ) , '%x%v %W' )
```

Some points:

- Use '%x%v %W' for ISO year and week
- Use YEARWEEK('your date',3) with 3 on second argument for ISO mode (start on Monday)

Tested with below dates to find first Monday:

- 2012-12-31 --> 2012-12-31
- 2014-01-07 --> 2014-01-06