# Given a date in MySQL, how can I determine the relative start of the week?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a `date_time` column in my table.

How do I get the date for the start of the week, i.e. the date `2011-01-09 13:44:00` would return `2011-01-07 00:00:00`?

I have looked over [MySQL Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) but wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

I tried something like this...

```
DATE_ADD( YEAR( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL WEEK( NOW( ) ) WEEK ) AS `start_of_week`
```

But all I got was `NULL`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you don't mind converting to Date first (from DateTime)](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/09/22/mysql-find-week-startend-based-on-week-number/)

```
DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
```

Also, the STR_TO_DATE function [is a possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317980/getting-first-day-of-the-week-in-mysql-using-week-no). Feed it your year and week concatenated right together, followed by your desired string-date format, which could then be cast to a datetime.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201003 Monday', '%X%V %W');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( DATE( NOW() ) , INTERVAL -WEEKDAY( NOW() ) DAY ) AS `start_of_week`
```

This returns 2011-05-30, so will be good if your first day of week is monday, otherwise you should to substract one more day.

I'm not sure for what did you use week/year