# mysql get current week, spanning last year and this year

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch all records from current week. But since Monday Dec 31st was in 2012, mysql treats it as week 53, instead of week 1 of 2013. How can I get around that?

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM `orders`
WHERE WEEK(`date_purchased`, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1)
    AND (
           (
            MONTH(`date_purchased`) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
            AND YEAR(`date_purchased`) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
            )
        OR (
            MONTH(`date_purchased`) = MONTH(NOW())
            AND YEAR(`date_purchased`) = YEAR(NOW())
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), week number 1 of the year is the first week with the majority of its days in the starting year, and while `week(date,1)` returns week 53 for '2012-12-31', [`week(date,3)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) or its equivalent [`weekofyear(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) correctly return week number [according to this standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788885/what-mode-for-mysql-week-complies-with-iso-8601), so:

```
weekofyear('2013-01-01') = weekofyear('2012-12-31') = 1
-- week starts on Monday, and 2012-12-31 is part of the first week of 2013

weekofyear('2012-01-01') = weekofyear('2011-12-31') = 52
-- last week of 2011 starts on 12-26, first week of 2012 starts on 01-02

weekofyear('2010-01-01') = weekofyear('2009-12-31') = 53
-- some years have 53 weeks

weekofyear('2007-01-01') != weekofyear('2006-12-31')
-- that's correct because the first day of 2007 was a Monday
```

Since your request is more specific, if you have to check if two days are part of the **same week of the same year**, this is still not enough to answer your question.

Instead of using `week`, or `weekofyear`, it's better to use [`yearweek(date,mode)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function, using `mode=3`, that returns the same week numbers as above, but also preceded by the year this week refers to:

```
yearweek('2013-01-01', 3) = yearweek('2012-12-31', 3) = 201301
yearweek('2012-01-01', 3) = yearweek('2011-12-31', 3) = 201152
yearweek('2010-01-01', 3) = yearweek('2009-12-31', 3) = 200952
yearweek('2007-01-01', 3) != yearweek('2006-12-31', 3)
```

so your query could become:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM `orders`
WHERE YEARWEEK(`date_purchased`, 3) = YEARWEEK(DATE(), 3)
```

Comment: @aoi this gives erroneous results for beginning of year: it will *not* match the beginning of the week that is in the previous year. For example on 2013-01-01, 2012-12-31 will not match although it is part of the same week.

Comment: @kmkaplan I'll update my answer and add some examples, but `weekofyear('2013-01-01')=weekofyear('2012-12-31')=1` because they are both considered part of the first week of 2013, and `weekofyear('2012-01-01')=weekofyear('2011-12-31')=52` because they are considered part of the last week of 2011

Comment: @fthiella this will not work. I am waiting for your edit: I will be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @kmkaplan i edited and added a few links, why you think this will not work?

Comment: @fthiella I said that “this will not work” to your claims regarding `weekofyear`. Your last edits concern `yearweek` which is another thing and *will* work. Now if only you removed the `weekofyear` (and `week`) part I could remove the downvote ;-)

Comment: @kmkaplan yes you are right, I understand, I only focused on week function because it was that function that wasn't working as expected, but using just week(date,3) is not enough so my answer could have been considered a little incomplete. now I hope it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) <= `date_purchased`
        AND `date_purchased` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using yearweek()?

Both
    yearweek('2012-12-31',1)
and
    yearweek('2013-01-01',1)
give the same result.

There're different ways to calculate yearweek, which is what the argument "1" is about.
For full list, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Answer (score -1):

I have a very similar but also a bit different question/issue (Unless of course I misunderstood his question).

I also have to list everything from the current week (in my case this is movies that will be projected at the cinema).

In my case however I need it so if for example you have movies to be projected at 30th of December 2013,  31st of December 2013 and 2nd of January 2014 and you are in the 2013s part of the week, to see all the movies of the current week (even those going to be projected in 2014) and also when you are in 2014s part of the week to again see all movies (even those that were projected in 2013).

Not having to specify the number of weeks in each year manually or having to specify the year manually since of course I need it to work every year without having to modify the code.

Here is my current SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM #__cinema_dates AS d LEFT JOIN #__cinema_film AS f on d.fid=f.id WHERE WEEK(d.date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) ORDER BY d.date ASC
```

Comment: You should not use answers as a place to post a 'me too' question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the comment feature at first.