# MySQL LEFT JOIN - Empty results unless all columns included

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have had no problems with this until the new year so I assumed it was a YEARWEEK problem but I think I have confirmed that it is not.

My original statement which no longer works (returns 0 results):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.family 
FROM report_tables.roc_test_results as t1 
LEFT JOIN report_tables.roc_capacity_standards as t2 
ON t1.item=t2.part_number 
WHERE YEARWEEK(t1.date_created)='201301' 
    AND t1.operation='TEST' 
    AND t1.result='Passed'
```

But the odd part is that this one works perfectly fine (returns 22 results):

```
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM report_tables.roc_test_results as t1 
LEFT JOIN report_tables.roc_capacity_standards as t2 
ON t1.item=t2.part_number 
WHERE YEARWEEK(t1.date_created)='201301' 
    AND t1.operation='TEST' 
    AND t1.result='Passed'
```

Does anyone know why this is no longer working?  The only difference is that I include all columns from t2 on the second query

Comment: try changing the order of columns in select list like t2.family,t1.*

Comment: @vidyadhar I tried your suggestion but unfortunately, that didn't help, but thanks!

Comment: can you reproduce it in a sqlfiddle?

Comment: i got it i tried with similar type just remove where and include all condition in on clause i.e,t1.item=t2.part_number and YEARWEEK(t1.date_created)='201301' AND t1.operation='TEST' AND t1.result='Passed'

Comment: @vidyadhar while that does work, it doesn't give the results I want, it will return all records, I only want records for this particular week, and only "passed" "Test" operations.  I also tried only using the date criteria in the WHERE but for some reason it keeps telling me query aborted and sometimes no results.

Comment: @chumkiu - If I can manage figuring out how to set up this sqlfiddle you speak of I will.  It may take a while, this is my first time with sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Geoff are you sure it's not a yearweek problem? it's strange if second query works and first doesn't, so maybe i am wrong, but what if you try to use YEARWEEK(t1.date_created,3)='201301'?

Comment: well, try to select `YEARWEEK(t1.date_created)` in the first query and delete the same in `where`. What values it give you?

Comment: @fthiella That was it, so my first assumption was correct but I didn't do enough digging.  I now see that MySQL states, if the week selected starts on a date from the previous year it will return 0 results.  Of course, it says that under WEEK() not YEARWEEK() which is why I missed it.  This solves my problem, thanks!  I have never had an answer from a comment so I assume that you would now put this into an answer so I can vote it correct right?

Comment: @Geoff i was not sure so i deleted my answer, now I've just undeleted it... hope it's okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Yearweek(date), you should use Yearweek(date,3) that returns the year and the week according to ISO standard.

If you try this:

```
SELECT yearweek('2013-01-01'), yearweek('2013-01-05')
201253; 201253
```

you'll see that this interval is considered as being part of week 53 of 2012, and 6th of January is considered to be the first week of 2013, while according to ISO standard they are part of the first week of 2013:

```
SELECT yearweek('2013-01-01',3), yearweek('2013-01-06',3)
201301; 201301
```

I think this might be the problem. Please see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191216/mysql-get-current-week-spanning-last-year-and-this-year/14191270#14191270) to a similar problem.