# SQL using insert and nested select statements where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a Work in Progress summary that feeds graphs for my boss, he wants to store the data so the graphs can show comparisons last year, last quarter, last month and today.

I had a couple sql statements that handle this fine but I was trying to consolidate into one statement.

**SQL:**

```sql
INSERT INTO `wip_summary` (`wk_num`, `year`, `a_cnt`, `ae_cnt`, `b_cnt`, `sm_cnt`, `xx_cnt`, `tm_cnt`, `svc_cnt`, `ci_cnt`, `a_amt`, `ae_amt`, `b_amt`, `tm_amt`, `sm_amt`, `xx_amt`, `svc_amt`, `ci_amt`)
   SELECT
      WEEK(CURDATE()),
      YEAR(CURDATE()),
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 10000
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `a_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ae_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 3500
                  AND `c_price` < 10000
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `b_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 600
                  AND `c_price` < 3500
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `sm_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` < 600
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `xx_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` = 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `tm_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `wo_type` = 'SERVICE ORDER'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `svc_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '1'
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `ci_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 10000
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `a_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = 1 THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `ae_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 3500
                  AND `c_price` < 10000
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `b_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` = 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `tm_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` >= 600
                  AND `c_price` < 3500
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `sm_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `c_price` < 600
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
                  AND `terms` <> 'TIME AND MATERIAL'
                  AND `wo_type` <> 'SERVICE ORDER'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `xx_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `wo_type` = 'SERVICE ORDER'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '0'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `svc_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0'
                  AND `contractInstall` = '1'
          THEN `c_price` ELSE 0 END) AS `ci_amt`
    FROM (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(`contract_price`, ',', ''), '$', '') AS Decimal(10,2)) AS `c_price`,
                 `emc`,
                 `contractInstall`,
                 `wo_type`,
                 `terms`
            FROM `orders`
    WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') AS `cp_tbl`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

What I am doing broken down:

1. Check to see if the records for this week in this year are in the database
2. Getting the count or summing the dollar amount based on specified criteria

It works great unless the week and year are in the table, then I get a row of column defaults.

So the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is what is failing me but I can't seem to put my finger on why or how.

Without the nested `SELECT` statement the `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` works, without the `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement the `SELECT` statement works.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Maybe the second WHERE must be replaced by AND.

Comment: Is wk_num in the iso format? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788885/what-mode-for-mysql-week-complies-with-iso-8601

Comment: @TomV Yes it is, as I mentioned, separately the SQL statements both work. Together is when I am having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by adding a `SELECT * FROM ()` statement wrapping the complex one I had.

```sql
INSERT INTO `wip_summary` (`wk_num`, `year`, `a_cnt`, `ae_cnt`, `b_cnt`, `sm_cnt`, `xx_cnt`, `tm_cnt`, `svc_cnt`, `ci_cnt`, `a_amt`, `ae_amt`, `b_amt`, `tm_amt`, `sm_amt`, `xx_amt`, `svc_amt`, `ci_amt`)
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT
      WEEK(CURDATE()),
      YEAR(CURDATE()),
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `a_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` =  1  [...]) AS `ae_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `b_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `sm_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `xx_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `tm_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `svc_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `ci_cnt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `a_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` =  1  [...]) AS `ae_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `b_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `tm_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `sm_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `xx_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `svc_amt`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `emc` = '0' [...]) AS `ci_amt`
    FROM (SELECT [...] AS `c_price`,
                 `emc`,
                 `contractInstall`,
                 `wo_type`,
                 `terms`
            FROM `orders`
            WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') AS `cp_tbl`) AS `vals`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

I may be wrong, but I believe the issue was that the `SELECT` statement that represented the values conflicted with the `INSERT`'s `WHERE` clause.

The `WHERE` inside the `FROM` statement had no conflict, when I removed it and simplified the `FROM` it still worked the same (inserting a row whether a record was present or not).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the second WHERE with AND.
If you don't the Select will always produce data. If you do, the select won't give data, because the year/weak combination already exists in the wip_summary.

Change this part:

```
        FROM `orders`
    WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') AS `cp_tbl`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

to

```
        FROM `orders`
    WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()))
AS `cp_tbl`;
```

Comment: The second `WHERE` is for the `INSERT` statement and the first `WHERE` is for the `SELECT` statement, if I replace the second with `AND` I get a `syntax error near 'AND...'` mysql error.

Comment: I figured that is where it is having issues, but replacing with the `AND` does not resolve. Separately the SQL statements work perfectly. I may just not be able to consolidate the statements as I had hoped, since the conflict is there.

Comment: You probably have changed it to 
|WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') AS `cp_tbl`
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()));


It must be:
|WHERE `auth_status` = 'ACTIVE') 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `wip_summary` WHERE `wk_num` = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND `year` = YEAR(CURDATE()))

AS `cp_tbl`;

Comment: Appreciate the answer, yeah I tried that. With parenthesis around the SELECT and using AND, without the parenthesis. Same syntax error.

Comment: Check where 'AS cp_cpl' is located. It must be after the where statements.