# SQL showing all weeks(52) in current year

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

how can I show all weeks(52) in **current** year

I have made this query:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(IF(DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y-%u') IS NULL,
                (DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y-%u')),
                DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y WEEK %u'))) AS CurrentDate,
    COALESCE(IF(SUM(q.totalExcl) IS NULL,
                0,
                SUM(q.totalExcl))) AS total
FROM
    expoled.ps_oxoquotation_quotationstate_history h
        RIGHT JOIN
    expoled.ps_oxoquotation_quotation q ON h.idQuotation = q.idQuotation
        LEFT JOIN
    expoled.ps_employee e ON h.idEmployee = e.id_employee
        INNER JOIN
    expoled.ps_sv_employee_meta m ON h.idEmployee = m.id_employee
WHERE
    h.idEmployee = 39
        AND YEAR(q.date_add) = YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
        AND h.idQuotationState = 3
GROUP BY IFNULL(CurrentDate, '')
```

I think I need to do something in here:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y WEEK %u'), 0) AS CurrentDate,
    IFNULL(SUM(q.totalExcl),0) AS total
FROM
```

I have tryed to put IFNULL but that gave me the same result

this is what I'm getting right now:

[image]

It show the current weeks from 5 to week 16.
There is also nothing in Week 1 till Week 4 because there is no data in. And there it needs to show just a simple zero(0)

So what I want is it needs to show standard from Week 1 till week 52 and if there is no data just 0

The query is working right now without any errors.

Comment: Weeks is always an interesting one. What sort of weeks are you talking about? Since you said 52, I assume you mean ISO weeks?

Comment: Yes ISO weeks full 52 weeks

Comment: IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y WEEK %u')) , 0) use this

Comment: It gave me the same result  IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.date_add, '%Y WEEK %u'), 0) AS CurrentDate,
    IFNULL(SUM(q.totalExcl),0) AS total

Comment: You will have to generate an extra (temp) table containing all dates of this year which you'd have to join with `q.date_add` to get all weeks in this year.

Comment: good one @Jens but can I make it without making an extra table?

Comment: Not directly related to your *problem*, but ISO weeks go up to 53, not 52. [MySQL has a week() function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11804076/562459).

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a fixed number of weeks, without a particular table, I tried this.
Table XX1 is just to make the test, you can substitute with one of your table.  If it has a number of records >=366 you can eliminate the CROSS JOIN.

```
CREATE TABLE XX1 (id INT);
INSERT INTO XX1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO XX1 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO XX1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO XX1 VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO XX1 VALUES (5);

SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(RN, '%Y w%u') AS CURR_WEEK
FROM 
  (SELECT @RN:=DATE_ADD(str_to_date(  CONCAT(YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) ,'0101'), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS RN
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT @RN:=DATE_ADD(@RN, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS RN 
   FROM (SELECT 1 AS DUM FROM XX1
           CROSS JOIN XX1 X2
           CROSS JOIN XX1 X3
           CROSS JOIN XX1 X4
         ) Y LIMIT 366
   ) X
   WHERE YEAR(RN)=YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
   ORDER BY 1;
DROP TABLE XX1 ;
```

Output:

```
    CURR_WEEK
1   2017 w00
2   2017 w01
3   2017 w02
4   2017 w03
5   2017 w04
...
51  2017 w50
52  2017 w51
53  2017 w52
```

I think you could use this in place of your query (I couldn't do any test on your query of course)

**Other (and hope last) version:**

```
SELECT Y.CURR_WEEK,
            COALESCE(SUM(qh.totalExcl), 0) AS total
        FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(RN, '%Y-%u') AS CURR_WEEK
                     FROM 
                      (SELECT @RN:=DATE_ADD(str_to_date(  CONCAT(YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) ,'0101'), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS RN
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT @RN:=DATE_ADD(@RN, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS RN 
                       FROM XX1
                       CROSS JOIN XX1 X2
                       CROSS JOIN XX1 X3
                       CROSS JOIN XX1 X4
                       ) X
                       WHERE YEAR(RN)=YEAR(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
                       ) Y
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT q.date_add, q.totalExcl, h.idEmployee 
                    FROM expoled.ps_oxoquotation_quotation q 
                    INNER JOIN expoled.ps_oxoquotation_quotationstate_history h ON h.idQuotation = q.idQuotation
                    WHERE h.idEmployee = 39 AND h.idQuotationState = 3) qh ON DATE_FORMAT(qh.date_add, '%Y-%u')=Y.CURR_WEEK 
        /* are these useless? */
        LEFT JOIN expoled.ps_employee e ON qh.idEmployee = e.id_employee
        LEFT JOIN expoled.ps_sv_employee_meta m ON qh.idEmployee = m.id_employee
        GROUP BY Y.CURR_WEEK
```

Comment: Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. I made an copy and pasted it and it gave me this error

Comment: Now I did run the first script that did work. the second script did also work but it gave the same result as the picture above from week 5 till week 16 without any errors db: http://i.imgur.com/VuoJU2t.png

Comment: Posted another version too (changed order of join)

Comment: Now I'm getting all weeks till 52 but the numbers are incorrect: http://i.imgur.com/5Wi4Bjj.png I think it gives results for all employee's

Comment: Same result with the numbers [total]

Comment: I think I need to change its location: WHERE idEmployee = 39 AND idQuotationState = 3)

Comment: When i do INNER JOIN the numbers are correct but the weeks are from week 5 till 16

Comment: Another new version...Can you try it pls?

Comment: This time it did work thanks mate for helping me really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB, it is really easy to build a table of weeks:

```
mysql> SELECT ('2017-01-02' + INTERVAL seq WEEK) AS wk FROM seq_0_to_53;
+------------+
| wk         |
+------------+
| 2017-01-02 |
| 2017-01-09 |
| 2017-01-16 |
| 2017-01-23 |
| 2017-01-30 |
| 2017-02-06 |
| 2017-02-13 |
| 2017-02-20 |
...
```

Based on that, you can:

- `JOIN` to your table and use `wk` as needed.
- Change the starting date to align with Sunday instead of Monday (or whatever)
- Go for as many weeks as you like
- Restrict the range after the fact with `WHERE wk BETWEEN ...`
- By fetching something like `CONCAT('2017 WEEK ', seq) AS iso` you can get the syntax you requested.