# Discrepancy in SQL and Pandas results for week of the year

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

I am using the SQL query `week(date)` and Pandas syntax `df['date_time'].dt.weekofyear` on the same dataset but the results seems to be different. I would appreciate guidance on the potential reason for the difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add output of the sql function and python function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql `WEEK` uses Sunday as start of week, use `ISO_WEEK` instead to have Monday as starting day or use `WEEK(date, 1)`. Pandas weekofyear should return ISO 8601. However, this function raises a Future Warning deprecation notice in pandas version >= 1.1.0

edit:
`ISO_WEEK` seems to be not a function for most SQL-dialects. Also the range of week-numbers returned might be important (i.e. starting with 0 or 1). In ISO 8601, 0 is not allowed, which means that for MySQL you would use `WEEK(date, 3)` instead.

As seen in this question: [What mode for MySQL WEEK() complies with ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788885/what-mode-for-mysql-week-complies-with-iso-8601)

Comment: Thanks so much @Patrick H. for your proposal. I have tried out ```ISO_WEEK``` and it seems it's not a Sql dialect. On the other hand, both ```WEEK``` and ```WEEK(date, 1)``` produce similar results.

Comment: Oh, right. ISO also defines the starting week of a year differently, than default `WEEK` does. What database server are you using? According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788885/what-mode-for-mysql-week-complies-with-iso-8601) you might need to use `WEEK(date, 3)` if you are using MySQL.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. ```WEEK(date, 2)``` produces similar results with Pandas ```dt.weekofyear```