# How to find the first Sunday of the month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I did not find any of examples for MySQL - all of them were quite complicated.

How can I `SELECT` the first Sunday of the month?

Comment: one more on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317980/getting-first-day-of-the-week-in-mysql-using-week-no

Answer (score 8):

So choose the first day of the month: `2012-01-01` (or whatever month and year you want).

Get the weekday index of the date. Indexes here are from 0 to 6.

Subtract that index from 6 and you will get how many days you need to add until the date is Sunday.

Add that amount of days to the chosen day.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2012-01-01 10:00:00", INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY("2012-01-01 10:00:00")) DAY);
```

Or:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2012-01-01", INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY("2012-01-01")) DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

So choose the first day of the month: 2021-08-01 (or whatever month and year you want).

SELECT ADDDATE( '2021-08-01' , MOD((8-DAYOFWEEK('2021-08-01')),7))

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Yes, right provide more details as other answer for this question. For that it will more helpfull for others