# Is it possible to auto create querys according specific values?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to create multiple querys choosing the day of week?

MYSQL query:

```
create table reservations (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  var_start datetime NOT NULL, 
  var_end  datetime NOT NULL
)
```

For example

```
var_day   = "3"   // Wednesday 
var_month = "11"  // November 
var_year  = "2018" 
var_start = "11:00”   // 11 am
var_end   = "13:00”  // 1 pm

//This will create all inserts according all wednesday on november 2018.
insert into table var_start = "07-11-2018 11:00:00" var_end = "07-11-2018 13:00:00"
insert into table var_start = "14-11-2018 11:00:00" var_end = "07-11-2018 13:00:00”
insert into table var_start = "21-11-2018 11:00:00" var_end = "07-11-2018 13:00:00”
insert into table var_start = "28-11-2018 11:00:00" var_end = "07-11-2018 13:00:00”
```

Here is the [html demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wndrLgq0/11/)

I will appreciate some links or concepts to search the correct information about automatic querys or this kind of concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One possibility is using a number generator. Will the input variables be always one particular day, one particular month, one particular year and so on.. ?

Comment: Yeah I understand that part; but at a time only **one** value will be input for these variables, right ?

Comment: I believe the `column1` is of date type, so the input should be in **YYYY-MM-DD** format instead.

Comment: Please clarify the datatype of the columns in the table. It would be better if you add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results to the question. I am working out a solution, and its complexity will vary on this.

Comment: I am not talking about the JS side code. Have you already created the MySQL table ? What is its structure ? What are the datatypes defined on the **MySQL table columns** ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually asking for, what query or queries do you want to make? perhaps you could supply an example? All I see at the js fiddle is a UI to choose some parameters values.

Comment: @EzioAuditore why are you using `bigint` to store date and time values. You should use native MySQL datatypes such as `date` and `time`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i added the correct information

Comment: @EzioAuditore Here is one idea: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jTgSLwaaVdGn5qQProJJK/0 ; Run it and check the results. I will prepare a formal answer in some time. But it will be basically utilizing `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` syntax.

Comment: @EzioAuditore do provide feedback on the posted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will be basically dynamically generating all the required dates within the query itself. And then use that result-set to Insert into the `reservations` table.

I have changed `id` column to Primary Key and Auto Increment (as it should be).

In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we will use a number generator from 0 to 4, as there can be at maximum 5 Wednesdays (and other weekdays) in a month.

Now we will try to get the first Sunday of the required month. For that, we will firstly create a date corresponding to first date of the month, using the input variable values for the month and year:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018','11','01'), '%Y%c%d')
```

`Concat('2018','11','01')` basically generates `20181101` string. We can then use [`Str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert it into [MySQL date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). We could have use [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function directly to get in `YYYY-MM-DD` format; but this approach should be robust in case the input month is `9` instead of `09`.

Now, we will use various [Datetime functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to determine the **nth** Wednesday. I have expanded over the answer originally given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405764/2469308

Number generator table will help us in calculating the 1st, 2nd, 3rd Wednesday and so on.. We can basically get the first Wednesday by adding 3 number of days to the first Sunday. Afterwards, we will basically add 7 days everytime to get next Wednesday in the month.

Eventually, we will use all these dates and [`AddTime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) to them for determining `var_start` and `var_end` accordingly. Also, there is a possibility that in the 5th day, it may cross to next month. So we will filter those out using `WHERE MONTH(..) .. AND YEAR(..) ..` conditions.

Finally, [`INSERT INTO.. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement will be used to insert into the `reservations` table.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7) [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jTgSLwaaVdGn5qQProJJK/1)**

```
create table reservations (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  var_start datetime NOT NULL, 
  var_end  datetime NOT NULL
);

/*
var_day   = "3"   // Wednesday 
var_month = "11"  // November 
var_year  = "2018" 
var_start = "11:00”   // 11 am
var_end   = "13:00”  // 1 pm
*/
```

---

**Query #1**

```
INSERT INTO reservations (var_start, var_end)
SELECT
  ADDTIME(dates.nth_date, '11:00') AS var_start, 
  ADDTIME(dates.nth_date, '13:00') AS var_end 
FROM 
(
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018','11','01'), '%Y%c%d') + 
  INTERVAL (6 - 
            WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018','11','01'), '%Y%c%d')) + 
            3 + 
           (7*nth)) DAY AS nth_date 
FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS nth UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4) AS num_gen
) AS dates
WHERE MONTH(dates.nth_date) = 11 AND 
      YEAR(dates.nth_date) = 2018;
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM reservations;

| id  | var_start           | var_end             |
| --- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2018-11-07 11:00:00 | 2018-11-07 13:00:00 |
| 2   | 2018-11-14 11:00:00 | 2018-11-14 13:00:00 |
| 3   | 2018-11-21 11:00:00 | 2018-11-21 13:00:00 |
| 4   | 2018-11-28 11:00:00 | 2018-11-28 13:00:00 |
```

---

In terms of input variables (prefixed with `:` for parametric queries), the query would looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO reservations (var_start, var_end)
SELECT
  ADDTIME(dates.nth_date, :var_start) AS var_start, 
  ADDTIME(dates.nth_date, :var_end) AS var_end 
FROM 
(
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(:var_year,:var_month,'01'), '%Y%c%d') + 
  INTERVAL (6 - 
            WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(:var_year,:var_month,'01'), '%Y%c%d')) + 
            :var_day + 
           (7*nth)) DAY AS nth_date 
FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS nth UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4) AS num_gen
) AS dates
WHERE MONTH(dates.nth_date) = :var_month AND 
      YEAR(dates.nth_date) = :var_year;
```