# MySQL - How do I aggregate by week and select the first day of the week?

Tags: mysql, datetime

With this query:

```
SELECT 
  fulfilled_at, 
  ROUND(SUM(adjusted_total_charge), 2) as val, 
  WEEK(fulfilled_at) as week 
FROM purchases 
WHERE fulfilled_at >= '2013-02-23 16:59:54 -0500' 
  AND fulfilled_at <= '2013-05-22 16:59:54 -0400'  
GROUP BY YEAR(fulfilled_at), WEEKOFYEAR(fulfilled_at)  
ORDER BY fulfilled_at ASC
```

I get this result:

```
2013-02-24 14:03:29 5570.00     8
2013-02-27 04:15:46 67354.25    8
2013-03-05 13:53:28 45298.00    9
2013-03-11 13:54:59 40751.80    10
2013-03-18 16:12:27 42863.25    11
2013-03-27 14:16:25 35449.45    12
2013-04-02 13:23:58 46326.75    13
2013-04-08 05:25:55 35905.45    14
2013-04-15 15:50:12 28910.19    15
2013-04-22 18:42:10 31960.00    16
2013-04-29 23:37:51 36610.10    17
2013-05-06 15:57:23 24511.40    18
2013-05-16 22:32:29 20675.20    19
2013-05-20 18:17:49 9343.00     20
```

Notice that the fulfilled_at that is being shown is not from a specific day of the week, so the intervals are not an even 7 days apart.  I'd like to have the dates 7 days apart, preferably starting on the Monday of each week.

Comment: You could try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317980/getting-first-day-of-the-week-in-mysql-using-week-no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat(year(fulfilled_at), 
    weekofyear(fulfilled_at),' Monday'), '%X%V %W')
from purchases
```

A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6a44/3) to demo

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not specifying which `fulfilled_at` to select from the set grouped by `YEAR(fulfilled_at), WEEKOFYEAR(fulfilled_at)`. In that set there are `n` number of `fulfilled_at` dates and MySQL just selects the first one.

You could only have them be 7 days apart if there happens to be a `fulfilled_at` date on the first day of each week.

I also notice that in your `GROUP BY` clause you are using the `WEEKOFYEAR` function but your select is using the `WEEK` function. Is that intentional? The `WEEK(date[,mode])` function allows you to specify which day of the week is considered to be the first, a mode value of 1 being Monday.

[From MySQL Documentation on WEEKOFYEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear)

> WEEKOFYEAR(date)
>
> Returns the calendar week of the date as a number in the range from 1
>   to 53. WEEKOFYEAR() is a compatibility function that is equivalent to
>   WEEK(date,3).