# Get the start date of a MySQL calendar week (weekyear)

Tags: mysql, group-by, database-performance, query-performance

**All date format in European (yyyy-mm-dd).**

I am trying find the corresponding start date for a week reported by the weekofyear(this is, week starting on Monday).

```
set @date0 ='2012-12-31';
set @date1 ='2013-01-01';
select weekofyear(@date0), weekofyear(@date1);
> 1, 1
```

[SQL Fidle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f938/1)
This is, both dates are in the first week of 2013. 
However, if I try to extract the year and weekofyear I will get different results (which means I need to find a different strategy):

```
set @date0 ='2012-12-31';
select year(@date0), weekofyear(@date0);
>2012,1
set @date1 ='2013-01-01';
select year(@date1), weekofyear(@date1);
>2013,1
```

[SQl Fidle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c24fd/2)
If I manually consult the calender I can see to which year they belong (2013).

---

this big case will output the week start date

```
set @date1 ='2012-01-01';

select 
    case when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 1 day)) then @date1
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 2 day)) then date_sub(@date1 , interval 1 day)
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 3 day)) then date_sub(@date1 , interval 2 day)
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 4 day)) then date_sub(@date1 , interval 3 day)
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 5 day)) then date_sub(@date1 , interval 4 day)
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_sub(@date1 , interval 6 day)) then date_sub(@date1 , interval 6 day)
        else date_sub(@date1 , interval 6 day) end as week_start_date;
>2011-12-26
```

[SQL Fidle 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a29/1)

and this big case will also generate the combo year-week

```
set @date1 ='2012-12-31';
select 
    case when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 1 day)) then concat(year(@date1),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 2 day)) then concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 1 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 3 day)) then concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 2 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 4 day)) then concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 3 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 5 day)) then concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 4 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        when weekofyear(@date1) <> weekofyear(date_add(@date1 , interval 6 day)) then concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 5 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1)) 
        else concat(year(date_add(@date1 , interval 6 day)),'-', if(weekofyear(@date1) < 10, '0','') ,weekofyear(@date1))  end as week_of_year;

> 2013-01
```

[SQL Fidle 4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/020d8f/1)

---

Now i either need to find an more elegant way of do it, or find a suitable strategy to include this in the group by condition. I was thinking in add an extra column to the table being grouped and -- after add an index --, group by week_of_year or by the week_start_date.

Does someone experienced have a better idea/strategy?

Notes: this is to be used in a database with over half million users, to Analise a certain action they perform and the group by condition will take other parameters (such as, but not limited to, demographics).

Comment: What do you actually want to end up with?  If you just want the first day of the (Monday-Sunday) week containing the given input, you can simply do `date - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY`; for weeks beginning on any other day, simply adjust by the relevant number of days.  To obtain the year and week number, why not simply use [`YEARWEEK(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek), `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%X-%V')` or `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%x-%v')`?

Comment: All what you need to know about that: [Getting first day of the week in MySql using Week No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317980/getting-first-day-of-the-week-in-mysql-using-week-no)

Comment: @eggyal try to do select yearweek('2013-01-01'), weekofyear('2013-01-01') and see if they return the same week...

Comment: They will if you supply to `YEARWEEK()` the optional ***`mode`*** argument with a value of `3`, as indicated under the definition of [`WEEKOFYEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear): "*`WEEKOFYEAR()` is a compatibility function that is equivalent to `WEEK(date,3)`.*"  That is, try `YEARWEEK('2013-01-01', 3)`.

Comment: @eggyal yearweek, indeed, works. Many thanks, this will give me the week start:  date select date_sub(@date2 , interval weekday(@date2)  day); :)

Comment: Don't forget to submit your answer so I can approve it :)