# How to sum order total amount by week

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve last 3 months records. I need to sum order total amount by week. I have made following query.

```
select CONCAT("Week", WEEK(created_at)) as week_number, sum(total_cost) 
from certified_diamond_orders 
where created_at > 2016-11-22 
and status = "delivered" 
group by week("created_at")
```

But I am only getting one record with this. Infact my table has 2 years entries. Also I was trying to figure out how I can pull week start date and end date to diplay on my chart.

Any suggestions where I am making mistake?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317980/getting-first-day-of-the-week-in-mysql-using-week-no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`week("created_at")` looks like you're trying to determine the week of the string `"created_at"` rather than the column `created_at`. Which might explain why you're only getting one row in your result.

The date `2016-11-22` also looks suspiciously like a sum instead of a date (`2016 - 11 - 22 = 1983` vs `"2016-11-22"`

Try this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('Week', WEEK(created_at)) AS week_number,
  SUM(total_cost)
FROM certified_diamond_orders 
WHERE
  created_at > '2016-11-22' AND
  status = 'delivered'
GROUP BY WEEK(created_at)
```

Comment: It worked. any idea how I can bring week start and end date in result?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(created_at)) DAY)` AS start_of_week, DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(created_at)) DAY) AS end_of_week`, depends on what day your weeks starts: Sunday or Monday. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql